# IIS 7 errors are not being displayed

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5

Hi I use IIS 7 locally and on the Server,
I'm able to run all ASP.NET pages with no problems.

Only when a page create an exceptions, instead of visualize any error message and details.

I get only an IE windows saying

```
Do you want open or download file ....
```

I already tried, in web.config customerror="off" and in IIS / ASP / Debugging > send error to browser but just does not work.

Any Ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like the `Content-Type` header is screwed up, and the browser doesn't know what to do with it, so it offers to download.

Comment: for Brad, the problem occur only if the code trow exceptions, otherwise is just working fine. Any ideas?

Comment: IIS/ASP is for classic ASP, not for ASP.NET, so your setting there won't help. customerror won't help either, as this is an unhandled exception. Can you check if there is any HTTP handler/module that catched the exception and generated the error page (which led to the download prompt) Failed request tracing or Fiddler 2 trace should provide you more hints.

Comment: Thanks Lex Li, using Failed Request Tracing help me to investigate the problem that seems a conflict in Global.asax. Thanks for your hit!

Comment: Please guys, if you down vote add a comment

Answer (score -1):

iis 7 unable send error message to browser such as asp classic and iis old version 
u can user error handler in cs file easily

Comment: hmm ... hard to understand what you are saying. Care to edit and try to clarify?

Comment: my mean is if you want see error in browser in iis7 you have different way to iis5 (located on windows xp and used for asp classic)

Comment: and sorry for bad english grammer i've been used